# pywinauto coordinates

Tags: python

when I was testing its examples, I was confused about its coordinates.

In the mspaint.py in Examples/

```
#make sure the pencil tool is selected

pwin.Tools2.Click(coords = (91, 16))
```

The Tools2 references the painting tools pannel. But I don't know what the (91,16) means,
the notes says “make sure the pencil tool is selected", But It seems that (91,16) is not point to the pencil whether from left-top or right-top window coordinate.

And if I manually select the brush tool, running the above code would not select the pencil,
so apparently it is not correct.

another confusing thing is that when I run the following code

```
  app.start_(ur"mspaint.exe")
        pwin=app.window_(title_re = ".*-Paint")
        pwin.print_control_identifiers()
```

the console shows that

```
AfxControlBar42u - 'Tools' (L4,T50,R4,B334)
```

What does (L4,T50,R4,B334) means? if left-top is (4,50), and the right-bottom is (4,334)
It apparently is not a rectangle.

Does anyone can help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you got it right, it seems you are dealing with a degenerate control with zero width.